Understanding Disabling Controls JavaSCript vs Code Behind
First time for any web dev, so this might be a really silly question because I don't know something very basic.
This JQuery disables all the input controls in the PanlDL panel:
$('#PanlDL *').attr('disabled', true);

This JQuery will find those disabled controls:
var NumDisabled = $('#PanlDL :disabled');

However, when I run this code in the form's LoadComplete event (which seems like the same thing) the 2nd JQuery above doesn't find the controls as disabled:
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "DiablTestKey", "$('#PanlDL *').attr('disabled', true);", True)

I've tried using Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript and also an Ajax Update Panel but they both have the same result. Similarly this line of code doesn't find the someCtrl as being disabled if that control was disabled in the code behind using the ScriptManager line above:
var isDisabld = $(someCtrl).is('[disabled]');

What is the difference between running the Javascript from code behind? Does it have something to do with the "key" parameter used in the ScriptManager call?
Thanks for any help,
Ken

The only difference is when you run the RegisterStartupScript, it will run after DOM is loaded.

Can you try if you are able to call any normal JavaScript function using ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript. Some function which do alert or console.log, so that you will get to know if this is any reference or any other issue.

It might have something to do with the key if you call RegisterStartupScript twice with the same key. See this old article

OK, so I think there may have been PostBack involved when I was testing this, which I still don't have handle on, totally. I'm disabling the controls client side, which wouldn't have updated them server side. So if PostBack was involved, the page would have been reloaded from the server, with the original, non-disabled controls. When a button is clicked, does the page get re-loaded before the code-behind processes?
